# Average and Max on python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, max, mean

Is it possible to do the max and mean operation at the same time on a dataframe. My goal is to create a Bar and Line graph for following data in Python.

1. Find top 3 countries with Maximum points {Germany, Canada , France }
2. For above found countries find the Average Price

Bar will on Max Points while the trend Lines will be on Average Price

```py
import numpy as np

dfrn1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'country' : np.array(['France', 'US', 'France', 'US', 'Germany', 'US', 'France', 'France', 'India', 'Canada' ]),
    'price' : np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,7]),
    'points' : np.array([98,88,90,90,100,69,87,87,87,99 ])
})

dfrn1
```

This is what I have

```py
country = dfrn1.groupby("country")

country.describe().head()

t1 = country.points.max().sort_values(ascending=False).head(4).reset_index(name='points')
t2 = country.price.mean().reset_index(name='price') 

mergedStuff = pd.merge(t1, t2, on=['country'], how='inner')
mergedStuff

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x= mergedStuff['country'],
        y= mergedStuff['points'],
        name="Maximum Points" ,
        marker=dict(color = '#47d2fc'),

    ))
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x= mergedStuff['country'],
        y= mergedStuff['price'],
        name="Average Price" ,
        line=go.scatter.Line(color="crimson"),
    ))        

fig.show()
```

Comment: Have you done any research into this, or attempted to solve the problem yourself? Calculating means and maxes of pandas DataFrames is a very common application, with many easy to find resources.

Comment: Yes sir Oliver I figure out a hard way to do this, just want to find some easy and efficient way to do this

Comment: if you include your method of doing this, others may be more easily able to point out how you can improve what you are doing

Comment: Thanks suraj Subramanian, PRICE should be the average, not the max like points. it is a 2 step problem

Comment: I did calculate the average price for the countries with top 3 points. Can you share the desired output you want.

Comment: For above data set, if we are looking for top 3 country then :                                                                                                        
France      mean(7,8,3,1)      max(87,87,90,98)
Canada      7        99
Germany      5       100


France      4.75        98
Canada      7        99
Germany      5       100

Answer (score 0):

```py
temp = dfrn1['points'].nlargest(3)
df2 = pd.merge(dfrn1, temp).sort_values('points', ascending=False) # creates a dataframe of top 3 countries with maximum points sorted in descending order

df2
df2["price"].mean()
```

Not the most effective solution, but hope it helps you !